# rollover image with buttons

Tags: html, forms, rollover

Is there a way to make a form input of type image to have a rollover image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this?

```
<input type="image" value="someValue" src="yourImage.gif" width="widthInPixels" height="heightInPixels" onmouseover="this.src='yourImageRollover.gif';" onmouseout="this.src='yourImage.gif';">
```

Comment: Get rid of the `javascript:` bit. That is a label (used for breaking out of loops (and since there isn't a loop, it is a waste of bytes)), not a language declaration.

Comment: removed the `javascript:` parts

Answer (score 2):

The same way as any other image. Change the `src` property when the `mouseover` event fires.

Answer (score 1):

I would just use a normal submit input and use css sprites on it.

http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites