# Why isn't my rollover image working?

Tags: javascript, css, rollover-effect

I have a code for my site, when an image is clicked a pop up window displays which is working fine.  However, whenever I roll over the first rollover works, but the original image before the rollover does not show anymore? why is this?

```
 <input name="image" type="image" onMouseOver= src="http://japanesefriend.zxq.net/images/x11_title.gif" onMouseOut= src="http://japanesefriend.zxq.net/images/level4_nouns_08.gif'"  value="Place Order" src="http://japanesefriend.zxq.net/images/level4_nouns_08.gif" onClick='styledPopupOpen("<img src=http://japanesefriend.zxq.net/flashcards/go.gif />")'  align=middle width=164 height=154>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see: [rollover image with buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5757714/rollover-image-with-buttons)

this seems to be a duplicate - the solution in the above question shoudl work for you.

For chrome (and even for other browsers), it is always a good idea to validate your html:
http://validator.w3.org/

Answer (score 2):

Use [CSS sprites](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/) for rollovers.

Answer (score 2):

Your HTML is invalid.

This...

```
onMouseOver= src="http://japanesefriend.zxq.net/images/x11_title.gif"
```

should be this...

```
onMouseOver="this.src='http://japanesefriend.zxq.net/images/x11_title.gif'"
```

Same for the `onMouseOut`...

```
onMouseOut="this.src='http://japanesefriend.zxq.net/images/level4_nouns_08.gif'"
```

***DEMO:*** http://jsfiddle.net/XBLfN/

---

Or you can eliminate `this.` and just do `src='http://...`

```
onMouseOver="src='http://japanesefriend.zxq.net/images/x11_title.gif'"
onMouseOut="src='http://japanesefriend.zxq.net/images/level4_nouns_08.gif'"
```

***DEMO:*** http://jsfiddle.net/XBLfN/1/

Comment: Ah! Ok I understand now! How would I add on the pop up window line to this though? It seems to not be working.  Thanks for taking your time to help me! So appreciated!